# how to change iexplore background color dynamically

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, winapi, mfc, win32-process

I am launching Internet Explorer from my Win32 application as a separate process. Later, I want to change this Internet Explore's background color dynamically from my app.  I can get the `HWND` of `IEXPLORE.EXE`:

```
HWND iexplor = GetForegroundWindow();   //assuming my explorer is active window currently
```

So, now with this `HWND` instance, is there a way I can change the background color of `IEXPLORE`?

Regular Win32 APIs fail because its a separate process (access denied).

Any idea/suggestions to this problem?

Below code fails because IE is a separate process:

```
HWND activeWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
if (activeWindow)
{
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));                  
    SetClassLongPtr(activeWindow, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG)brush);

    InvalidateRect(activeWindow, NULL, TRUE);
    int redraw =  ::UpdateWindow(activeWindow);
}
```

Comment: This is unlikely to work well in any scenario, what/why specifically do you want to do?  change the chrome colour?  - there isn't much of that in recent versions, change the colour of the displayed web page? - The latter is possible with COM or MAA

Comment: This sounds completely ill advised. Some machines may not have IE. There could be massive variation in the way IE is implemented, its hierarchy of processes and windows. Hoping that you might be able to hack the class background brush like that shows a lack of appreciation for how Win32 works. You will only really gain satisfaction here when you adjust your expectations to be more realistic.

Answer (score 0):

First, IE is not guaranteed to be in the foreground when you need it.  You should instead enumerate the open `HWND` handles of the specific process that you are launching.  Look at [`EnumThreadWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633495.aspx), [`EnumChildWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494.aspx), etc.

Second, once you have the proper `HWND` to an IE window, you can [get its `IHTMLDocument2` interface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249232), and then use IE's DOM interfaces to manipulate the browser's content as needed.  Such as by setting the [IHTMLDocument2::bgColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533506.aspx) property. Or using the [`IHTMLDocument2::body`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752585.aspx) property to retrieve the [`IHTMLBodyElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704297.aspx) interface for the `<body>` element and then setting the [IHTMLBodyElement::bgColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869367.aspx) property.